# Qt for WebAssembly missing

Tags: javascript, qt, qt5, webassembly

I followed https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-setup-webassembly.html to install WebAssembly for my Qt which is the latest one for the open-source version 5.14.2.

The step 1 says "Use the Qt maintenance tool to install Qt for WebAssembly". Unfortunately, I can't find it (Qt for WebAssembly) both the Qt for macOS (Catalina) and one for Win 10.

Note that my Maintain tool on the first time blamed there was no default repo, thus I have to add manually one at http://download.qt.io/online/qtsdkrepository/mac_x64/root/qt/

Any idea how to fix that? Thanks.

[image: Qt maintenance tool for macOS]

Comment: The repo URL you used looks like it only contains packages for macOS as target. Which online installer is that? Maybe you need to re-download the latest online installer and make sure the old Qt installation dir is nuked (to make sure the maintenance tool does not pick up any stale settings).

Comment: It’s for macOS only. However, if you go up for few levels you will see repos for other systems. The maintenance tool for Win 10 has the problem (missing Qt for WASM). I have installed my Qt from the latest offline installer (5.14.2). I cannot use online one since my account has been expired the evaluation time (the online installer always quits and suggests to use offline one)

Comment: That's strange. The account is free and shouldn't require any commercial license.